# Change the cursor icon in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am looking to change the cursor in the viewer when I activate my tool in the viewer. I have tried updating the cursor CSS value for the canvas of the viewer but it seems to be overwritten to the default viewer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show what you've tried.

If you add this css:

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer > .canvas-wrap > canvas {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Just replace 'cursor: pointer' with the type of cursor you'd like. Be sure to add the `!important` value or it won't override the default cursor.

The canvas is generated after the document is ready, so you'd need to wait for the appropriate events if you are looking to override the cursor style with JS.

Edit:

I noticed you said you were activating it from a tool, so to set the cursor like this with js:

```
const viewerCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0] //may need to ensure [0] is the viewer canvas if multiple canvas's

viewerCanvas.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer !important');
```

You just need to unsure that you handle both tool-activated and tool-deactivated toggle events.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set the cursor style:

```
viewer.canvas.style.cursor = "pointer" | "progress" ...
```

And beware that that'd be overwritten again when navigation tools are activated so to stick to a cursor at all times follow the other answer to override by class name in your stylesheet with the `!important` rule.

Answer (score 0):

As I stumbled across the same problem I found the way other tools implement this behavior:

You can set the cursor by implementing the `getCursor` function in your [tool](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/ToolInterface/) (your tool must be active and have the highest priority). This seems to be the easiest and safest method to set the mouse cursor. Also note that an cursor image should be 32x32px for best compability [according to mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property).

Look in the `OrbitDollyPanTool` for an example:

```js
this.getCursor = function ()
  {
    if (!_useCustomCursors)
    return null;

    switch (_activeMode) {

      case "freeorbit":
      case "orbit":
        return 'url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto';

      case "dolly":
        return "url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto";

      case "pan":
        return "url(data:image/png;base64,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), auto";}

    return null;
  };
```